# Symfony 2 "losing" form data in post

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here since this is the way I have my app working. Some how, in this case, my form data is not present. When I debugged the app I've found out that when I submit the form, by default, the first breakpoint is in app_dev.php, all the post data is present, and for all other forms I have, the app continues to the respective controller, but in this case, it goes again to app_dev.php and all post data is lost. What am I missing here?

The method in the controller:

```
public function doCreateNewProjectAction(Request $request) {
    $projectForm = self::getProjectModel(new ProjectEntity());
    $projectForm->handleRequest($request);
    $projectEntity = $projectForm->getData();
    (...)
```

The twig:

```
<form method="POST" action="./doCreateNewProject">
    <div class="field-line">
        <div class="field-label">{{ form_label(projectForm.name) }}</div>
        <div class="field-element">{{ form_widget(projectForm.name) }}</div>
        <div class="field-error">{{ form_errors(projectForm.name) }}</div>
    </div>
    (...)
    <div class="field-line">
        {{ form_widget(projectForm.create) }}
    </div>
</form>
```

The config:

```
project-new-do:
    pattern: /projects/new/doCreateNewProject/
    defaults: { _controller: CCAppBundle:Project:doCreateNewProject }
```

I've tried several things and I haven't been very lucky finding a solution in Google.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does self::getProjectModel return?

Comment: It would be best to have the action be the dynamic `path('project-new-do')` rather than set as `./doCreateNewProject`. Not sure if that would solve your problem though.